# PowerShell Move-Item $filename

Tags: powershell

I searched, i googled.. about to smash my head on the table

how come this will not work?

```
move-Item  $path$file $targetdir
```

it gives me an error
Move-Item : An object at the specified path C:\Repository\test.csv
                                                                                         does not exist.

now if i debug this and i output using

```
write-output move-Item  $path$file $targetdir
```

and take that output and paste it (file name with path and destination) it works!

and trust me the file is there. =\

---

Code below

```
    $path = 'C:\test\'
$TimeStamp = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy_hh-mm-ss"
$LogFile = Get-Date -Format "MM_dd_yyyy"
$targetdir = "C:\test\Uploaded\"

#Get-ChildItem -path $path\* -Include *.csv | foreach-object {$_.Fullname} | Format-Table name -hidetableheaders  | Out-File $path\list.txt

Get-ChildItem -path $path\* -Include *.csv | Format-Table name -hidetableheaders  | Out-File $path\list2.txt
get-content C:\test\list2.txt | where {$_ -ne ""} | out-file C:\test\list.txt
Remove-Item  C:\test\list2.txt

$list = get-content C:\test\list.txt 


foreach ($file in $list)
{
    $ftp = "ftp://REMOVED/$file"
    "ftp url: $ftp"
    $webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp)
    "Uploading $file..."

    $succeeded = $true;
    &   {
    trap { $script:succeeded = $false; continue }
    $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $path+$file)
        }
if ($succeeded) 
        { 

        echo $file 'Was successfully uploaded!' $Timestamp >> logfile$LogFile.log
        move-Item  -path $path$file -destination $targetdir
        #test-path $path$file
        } 

    else 
        { 

        echo $file 'Was not successfully uploaded, will retry later' $Timestamp >> logfile$LogFile.log

        }   


}

exit
```

Comment: have you tried just putting double quotes around `"$path$file"` to invoke string interpolation?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Correct I have, same error.

Comment: What happens if you do `Test-Path "$path$file"`? I am taking into account your last line in your question

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Output = True without the " and with

Comment: I just tried it, and was unable to replicate the issue. At this point we need more information. What version of PowerShell? Are $path, $file, and $targetdir strings? FileInfo objects? PSCustom objects? I used those variables, set them as strings, and ran your command without issues. `$path='c:\temp\'` `$file='list.csv'` and `$targetdir='c:\temp\test'` worked without errors (and moved the file)

Comment: @TheMadTechnician `Major  Minor  Build  Revision
2      0      -1     -1`     I am setting the filename with `foreach ($file in $list)` where the list is created with  `Get-ChildItem -path $path\* -Include *.csv | Format-Table name -hidetableheaders  | Out-File $path\list.txt`    and path is set as a variable $path = 'c:\test\'

Comment: As a rule of thumb, never use `Format-List` or `Format-Table` output in operations. It should only be used for display of data after it has been processed.

Answer (score 2):

Basics are:

- Test-Path before you move it (file and destination)
- Move the file, ensure you have permission (force it to move)

so:

```
echo $targetdir
echo "$path$file"
if (!(Test-Path $targetdir)) {
    New-Item -ItemType directory $targetdir
}
if(Test-Path "$path$file") { 
    Move-Item "$path$file" $targetdir -Force
} else {
    echo "file does not exist"
}
```

If you loop over a collection you have to use the ".FullName" property of the object:

```
Get-ChildItem $path | ForEach-Object { Move-Item $_.FullName $targetdir -Force }
```

Answer (score 1):

Does the target directory already exist?  I believe Move-Item will fail if the target directory doesn't exist.  If that's the case, you can simply test for existence of the directory beforehand and then create as necessary.

```
If (!(Test-Path -Path $targetdir)) {
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $targetdir
}
```

Comment: Yes the directory is there works fine if i dont use Variables but use exact strings @kris powell

Answer (score 0):

How about this then:

```
ForEach($File in $List){
    Join-Path $path $file | Move-Item -Dest $Targetdir
}
```

**Edit:** Also... your creation of list.txt, it bothered me so I had to comment. Format-Table should be used for formatting text, not for selecting a value to output to a file. There's a better way to do that, consider this alternative:

```
Get-ChildItem "$path*.csv" | Select -ExpandProperty Name | Out-File $pathlist.txt
```

Since you say that `$path = 'C:\test\'` you are adding extra backslashes in there that may cause issues for some commands.

**Edit2:** Ok, if that doesn't work, why not work with the files themselves instead of outputting to a file, importing from that file, and then working with things.

```
$path='c:\test\'
$TargetDir = 'c:\test\NewDir'
$FileList = Get-ChildItem $path*.csv
If(!(Test-Path $TargetDir)){New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $TargetDir|Out-Null}
$FileList | Move-Item -Destination $TargetDir
```

Then if you really want a list of those file names just pipe $FileList to Select and then to Out-File

```
$FileList | Select -ExpandProperty Name | Out-File 'C:\Test\list.txt'
```

Here, look through this and see if there's anything you like. I made a few changes, such as declaring paths at the beginning for everything, I moved the WebClient object creation outside of the loop, and changed how things are displayed on screen. Plus I skip the entire exporting to text file and re-importing it.

```
$path = 'C:\test'
$ftpaddr = 'ftp://ftp.example.com/uploads'
$TimeStamp = Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"
$LogFile = Get-Date -Format "MM_dd_yyyy"

$LogDir = "C:\Test\Logs"
If(!(test-path $LogDir)){New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $LogDir | Out-Null}
$targetdir = 'C:\test\Uploaded'
If(!(test-path $targetdir)){New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $targetdir | Out-Null}

$list = Get-ChildItem -path $path\* -Include *.csv

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient

"ftp url: $ftpaddr"

foreach ($file in ($list|select -ExpandProperty Name))
{
    $uri = New-Object System.Uri(("$ftpaddr/$file"))

    Write-Host "Uploading $file... " -NoNewline -ForegroundColor White

    $succeeded = $true
    &   {
    trap { $script:succeeded = $false; continue }
    $webclient.UploadFile($uri, "$Path\$file")
        }

if ($succeeded) 
        {
        Write-Host "Success!" -ForegroundColor Green
        "$Timestamp`t$File was successfully uploaded!" | Out-File "$logdir\logfile$LogFile.log" -Append
        move-Item  -path "$path\$file" -destination $targetdir
        } 

    else 
        { 
        Write-Host "Failed! Will retry later." -ForegroundColor Red
        "$Timestamp`t$File was not successfully uploaded, will retry later" | Out-File "$logdir\logfile$LogFile.log" -Append
        }   

}
```

Comment: Look at the full code above that i created. Let me know if this helps. This will help understand it better. im basically uploading after i get the list and moving the files into an Uploaded folder.

Comment: I think i was over thinking it =| and it got messy

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Thank you @TheMadTechnician. Hopes this helps everyone

```
$TimeStamp = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy_hh-mm-ss"
$LogFile = Get-Date -Format "MM_dd_yyyy"

$path='C:\test\'
$targetDir = 'C:\test\Uploaded\'
$fileList = Get-ChildItem $path*.csv
If(!(Test-Path $TargetDir)){New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $TargetDir|Out-Null}
$fileList | Select -ExpandProperty Name | Out-File 'C:\test\list.txt'

$list = get-content C:\test\list.txt 
foreach ($file in $list)
{
    $ftp = "ftp://REMOVED/$file"
    "ftp url: $ftp"
    $webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp)
    "Uploading $file..."

    $succeeded = $true;
    &   {
    trap { $script:succeeded = $false; continue }
    $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $path+$file)
        }
if ($succeeded) 
        { 

        echo $file 'Was successfully uploaded!' $Timestamp >> logfile$LogFile.log
        move-Item  -path $path$file -destination $targetdir$Timestamp"_"$file
        #test-path $path$file
        } 

    else 
        { 

        echo $file 'Was not successfully uploaded, will retry later' $Timestamp >> logfile$LogFile.log

        }   


}

exit
```

Comment: Glad you got it working, just for the sake of maybe learning a technique or two take a look at what I just added to my answer and maybe there'll be a thing or two that you want to incorporate into your script sometime.